# PHP generating a .php.vcf file instead of .vcf file

Tags: php, vcf-vcard

I have a feature in my PHP website where a user can download a vcard file for an employee, however the file being generated is .php.vcf and isn't supported on mobile.How can i change the file format to .vcf, The simplified PHP code for the vcf generation is below.

```
function generate_vcard($fn,$ln){
$text = 'BEGIN:VCARD' . "\r\n";
$text .= 'VERSION:3' . "\r\n";
$text .= 'Firstname:'.$fn . "\r\n";
$text .= 'Firstname:'.$fn . "\r\n";
$text .= "END:VCARD"."\r\n";
return $text;
}

$generated_text = generate_vcard('John', 'Smith');
header('Content-Type: text/vcard');
echo $generated_text;
```

The vcard is downloading, the problem is with the extension as mentioned above that is '.php.vcf' is being generated instead of '.vcf'.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to add content disposition and put filename there:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.vcf"');
```

Look at [header()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) documentation, specifically in the **"Example #1"**